# Call function in derived class (from interface), from base class

Tags: wpf, class, asynchronous, system.reactive, base-class

EDIT: Editting to focus the question better.

How do I call a method from a derived class, in the base class.  I have several classes that inherit from BaseClass.  All the derived classes implement IValidation, so have an implementation of the ValidateInput method.

```
interface IValidation
{
    public void ValidateInput(string userInput);
}

Public BaseClass : ViewModelBase
public string UserInput
{
    get { return _UserInput; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _UserInput) return;
        _UserInput = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => UserInput);

        //I want to call my validation method here
        //ValidateInput(UserInput);

        UserInputStream.OnNext(value); //UserInputStream is defined as readonly Subject<string> MyPropertyStream = new Subject<string>();
     }
}

public class DerivedCLassOne : BaseClass, IValidation
{
  public DoStuff
  {
       //subject Stream for UserInput
       UserInputStream
          .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
          .ObserveOn(Application.Current.MainWindow)
          .Subscribe(GetResults);
  }

  public async void GetResults(string userInput)
  {
      //do stuff
  }

  public void ValidateInput(string userInput)
  {
       //Do validation stuff
  }
}
```

Because there are 5 or 6 different classes derived from the base class, I can use a fully defined path to the ValidateInput method in the BaseClass (DerivedClassOne.ValidateInput) because depending on what is happening, the derived class will be different.  So the BaseClass needs to know to just use the ValidateInput method in the derived class that is currently in use, like the UserInputStream.OnNext(value); call does.

Can this be done with RX (Reactive Extensions)? Would it help to implemnent IValidation on the base class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could expose a stream which represents the validity of the user input:

```
class BaseClass 
{
    IObservable<bool> IsUserInputValid 
    { 
       get 
          { 
            return UserInputStream
                .Throttle(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .Select(x => IsValid(x))
                .ObserveOn(Application.Current.MainWindow);
           }
     }

     private bool IsValid(string userInput) { return whether the input is valid }
 }
```

And then bind the submit button and validation message to the IsUserInputValid property.

I suggest you have a look at the great [Reactive UI](http://reactiveui.net/) framework.